# Como pegar o input anterior ao button?

Tags: jquery

Tenho alguns `input` do tipo texto seguidos de `buttons`:

```
<input type="text" />
<button>inserir</button>
<input type="text" />
<button>inserir</button>
<input type="text" />
<button>inserir</button>
<input type="text" />
<button>inserir</button>
```

Preciso, ao pressionar o botão, pegar o valor do `input` acima do mesmo.

Como fazer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar [**.prev**](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) que seleciona o elemento anterior:

```js
$("button").on("click", function(){
   var texto = $(this).prev().val();
   console.log(texto);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
<button>inserir</button>
<input type="text" />
<button>inserir</button>
<input type="text" />
<button>inserir</button>
<input type="text" />
<button>inserir</button>
```